# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderator

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: PearsonArtPhoto]
[image: called2voyage]
[image: Hohmannfan]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: **Habemus moderatores (pro tempore)!**

Comment: Congratulations guys!

Comment: I want to welcome Hohmannfan onto the team as a good addition, and thank called2voyage and Pearson for their guidance and support during my time as moderator. I'm stepping down now to focus on work, but it was a very good experience, and i look forward to watching the site grow as a regular member.

Comment: @kimholder: I really appreciated your good work the last few months. I hope you will still be around the site as you have time. And more than that, I wish you continued success on [Moonwards](http://www.moonwards.com/).

Comment: Congrats, Hohmannfan! Good to have you on board!